# What is the efficient way to group multiple columns of a table to get the output as shown?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I use to track the amount of times I access a File in a certain Directory.  The following is a sample...

```
DirectoryName    FileName
A                Ab.pdf
B                bc.pdf
C                cd.pdf
A                de.pdf
A                kl.mp3 
B                pq.pdf
B                pq.pdf
B                pq.pdf
```

Each time a file is accessed it's Directory and Name are added.

Also, please note that a File may not occur in more than one Directory.

Please click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xdpd.png) for a sample of the table on which this is based.

I would like the output to occur like this...

```
Directory       DirectoryCount        FileName           FileCount
A               3                     Ab.pdf             1
                                      de.pdf             1
                                      kl.pdf             1
B               4                     bc.pdf             1
                                      pq.pdf             3
C               1                     cd.pdf             1
```

Here `DirectoryCount` is how many times the Directory has been accessed and `FileCount` is how many times the file has been accessed.

Please click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24PeN.png) for an example of the output that I wish to mimic, though I wish for each File to appear just once.

Comment: This makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: So what is the better way?

Comment: 1) Where are rows for directory `F`. Is it the last row? Then why not put directoryname and count in that row 2) Why does your fourth row `de.pdf` has directory name as null. And by this logic, where is `kl.pdf` in output?

Comment: In the output should `de.pdf` and `kl.mp3` be displayed under `ab.pdf`, and row for `DirectoryName` `F` displayed?

Comment: I have edited the question. Actually, I want Directory Name and Count, File Name and Count in the same row. There is no relationship among the directories or files.

Comment: Does this latest update mean that we should show the the first `FileName` for a `Directory` in with the rest of the `Directory`'s information and tack surplus `FileName`s onto the end of the list, or should they be grouped together?

Comment: Can a `FileName` occur more than once in the source table?

Comment: They should appear only once in the output with the count.

Comment: Will there always be the count of `Filename`s always be greater than that of  `DirectoryName`s?

Comment: @toonice Yes. It will be always equal or greater.

Comment: In regards your snapshot, do you want us to display an entry for each repeated `FileName` or just one of each distinct value (along with the count of repeated files)?

Comment: Updated Answer with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN directoryCountFinder.DirectoryName = LAG( directoryCountFinder.DirectoryName ) OVER ( ORDER BY directoryCountFinder.DirectoryName ) THEN
               ''
           ELSE
               directoryCountFinder.DirectoryName
       END AS DirectoryName,
       CASE
           WHEN directoryCountFinder.DirectoryName = LAG( directoryCountFinder.DirectoryName ) OVER ( ORDER BY directoryCountFinder.DirectoryName ) THEN
               ''
           ELSE
               CONVERT( VARCHAR( 10 ),
                        DirectoryCount )
       END AS DirectoryCount,
       FileName,
       FileCount
FROM ( SELECT DirectoryName AS DirectoryName,
              COUNT( DirectoryName ) AS DirectoryCount
       FROM tblTable
       GROUP BY DirectoryName
     ) directoryCountFinder
JOIN ( SELECT DirectoryName AS DirectoryName,
              FileName AS FileName,
              COUNT( FileName ) AS FileCount
       FROM tblTable
       GROUP BY DirectoryName,
                FileName
     ) fileCountFinder ON directoryCountFinder.DirectoryName = fileCountFinder.DirectoryName;
```

When I tested my statement against a test database created using the sample data provided, the output occurred as specified.

The logic that I used to form my statement was that we needed a count of how many times each Directory occurred and a count of how many times each File occurred in the list provided.

To count the number of times that each Directory occurred I used the following query...

```
SELECT DirectoryName AS DirectoryName,
       COUNT( DirectoryName ) AS DirectoryCount
FROM tblTable
GROUP BY DirectoryName
```

I used a similar query to count the number of times each File occurred...

```
SELECT DirectoryName AS DirectoryName,
       FileName AS FileName,
              COUNT( FileName ) AS FileCount
       FROM tblTable
       GROUP BY DirectoryName,
                FileName
```

`DirectoryName` is included here as I will need it to join the results from this subquery to the results from the other one.

Once the two subqueries are joined, we have a dataset that looks like the desired output, except that each value of `FileName` and `FileCount` is repeated.  Thus I apply `CASE` statements that test to see if the value of `DirectoryName` is the same in the current record as it was in the previous record, and if it is then it outputs empty strings (`''`'s) rather than the field values.

Since `DirectoryCount` is a number then all values in that field in the output would also be numbers if you simply listed the value of `DirectoryCount`, including the empty string `''`, which would appear as `0`.  But if we format `DirectoryCount` as a string for the output, then the empty string will appear as an empty string, i.e. a blank value, hence the use of `CONVERT( VARCHAR( 10 ), DirectoryCount )`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: Missing line added to code.  Please try the new Answer whilst I research your message.

Comment: Answer updated.  Please note that I am still setting up my first copy of SQL-SERVER thus it could be a little while before I am able to test my code.  It would help the quality of your Question if you were to include a script to generate and populate your sample table.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you accept this as the most suitable Answer provided and that it does indeed answer your Question, then please feel free to accept it by clicking on the tick beside the top of the Answer.

Comment: Hi, I have modified the question. May you help to get the output. Thanks

Comment: Please modify your question to include `( 'B', 'PQ.PDF' )` and `( 'C', 'PQ.PDF' )` in your sample data.  Please update your two desired outputs accordingly.

Comment: I have added ('pq.pdf') in B but NOT in 'C' because same file cannot be in two different directories.

Comment: Strange, but okay.  Please change `( 'C', 'PQ.PDF' )` to a second `( 'B', 'PQ.PDF' )`.

Comment: A file cannot exist twice in the same folder.

Comment: The image that you attached to your Question suggests that it can, and this is where `FileCount` comes from.

Comment: Actually, when I access the file it will be stored in a table with its directory name. Depends on how many times the file is accessed. You are seeing that table in the above image. I will upload the image of that table.

Comment: Then if a filename can not exist in more than one directory (or at least the same file can not), and a file / filename can not exist more than once in that directory, then will `FileCount` ever be more than `1`?  If so, then how?  If not, then should we still include it in our output?

Comment: File exist only once in a directory. The image I uploaded is the table where I store the number of accesses. For instance, I clicked on the file 5 times, the directory name and file name will be saved in the table 5 times. And the count will be 5.

Comment: Do we need to replicate that statistic in our Answer?  If so, then you will need to either add a field to the source table that shows how many accesses have been performed, or you will need to add a row with `DirectoryName` and `FileName` for every access.  If we do not replicate that statistic, then should we just put `1` every time for `FileCount` or just dump the field altogether?  Also, is `DirectoryCount` to be a count of all the files in a Directory or a count of the amount of times a file in that directory has been accessed?

Comment: I am adding a row every time the file is accessed. DirectoryCount is how many times the directory is accessed and fileCount is how many times the file is accessed.

Comment: I have both queries developed and tested.  They should be up shortly.  I shall have an updated explanation up soon after that.

Comment: Code posted as per the newly edited Question.  Explanation pending.  May I have your permission to rephrase your Question based upon our correspondence?

Comment: Thanks a lot, It is working. Yeah sure, you can rephrase it.

Comment: Edit to Question made.  Explanation added shortly.

Comment: Explanation of Answer added.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (DirectoryName NVARCHAR(1),FileNames NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
('A','Ab.pdf'),('B','bc.pdf'),('C','cd.pdf'),('A','de.pdf'),('A','kl.mp3')
SELECT * FROM @table -- your table
;WITH A AS (
SELECT DirectoryName, COUNT(DirectoryName) DirectoryCount FROM @table 
GROUP BY DirectoryName )  
SELECT CASE WHEN rowid = 1 THEN A.DirectoryName ELSE '' END DirectoryName, 
CASE WHEN rowid = 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.DirectoryCount) ELSE '' END DirectoryCount,
    B.FileNames,C.Filecount
FROM A LEFT JOIN (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DirectoryName ORDER BY DirectoryName)
rowid, DirectoryName, FileNames FROM @table 
) B ON A.DirectoryName = B.DirectoryName LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT DirectoryName,FileNames,COUNT(FileNames) Filecount FROM @table GROUP BY FileNames,DirectoryName)
C ON C.FileNames = B.FileNames AND B.DirectoryName = C.DirectoryName --your output
```

Comment: The filenames are redundant.

Comment: I have uploaded a snapshot. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Thats your table or thats your output after my query?

Comment: That is the output after your query.

Comment: what is your expected output, please can you tell?

Answer (score 0):

I can't get my local or SQLfiddle server working to check but you'll need something like this:

```
    select 
    DirectoryName,
    count(*) over( partition by directoryName) as DirectoryCount,
    FileName,
    count(*) over (partition by directoryname,filename) as filenameCount
    from tblTable
  order by DirectoryName,filename
```

To get the spacing, use your front end to detect changes in DirectoryName. If you want you can also select `ROW_NUMBER OVER (partition by DirectoryName)` and only show the `1`s

Also this option (again, front-end for removing dupes)

```
select d.DirectoryName, d.DirectoryCount , f.Filename,f.FileNameCount from
(
select DirectoryName,
count(*)as DirectoryCount
 from tblTable
group by DirectoryName
) as d
inner join
(
select DirectoryName, FileName,
count(*)as filenameCount
 from tblTable
group by DirectoryName,FileName
) as f
on d.directoryName=f.DirectoryName
order by DirectoryName, FileName
```